# pushing the innerText from 3 elements results in an array with 5 values?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm getting two extra/unexpected array entries that are undefined. These show up when I iterate over an array of element nodes with 3 entries and push the values into another array:

I have a select element with 4 options in it. I want to put the last 3 options.innerText into an array

```
<select>
  <option>skip me</option>
  <option>text1</option>
  <option>text2</option>
  <option>text3</option>
<select>
```

I made a variable and grabbed the nodes:

```
var options = document.querySelectorAll('select option:not(:first-child)')
```

this gave me an array with 3 option elements in it as confirmed in the console

```
>>options
<<[<option>text1​</option>​, 
   <option>text2​</option>​, 
   <option>text3​</option>​]
```

options.length is 3.

iterating over the array proceeds as expected, but also includes a function in the log?

```
>>for (i in options){console.log(options[i])}
<< <option>text1</option>
   <option>text2</option>
   <option>text3</option>
<< 3
<< function item() {[native code]}
```

When I iterate over the array and push the innerText into a new array, I get not 3, but 5 entries in the array

```
>>var texts = [];
>>for (i in options){texts.push(options[i].innerText)}
```

This gives me an array texts with 5 values: ['text1','text2','text3',undefined,undefined]

texts.length is 5

Why am I getting those two extra array entries?

I'm sure this is something elementary that I just haven't come across yet, can anyone explain?

Comment: Don't use `for in` over arrays. Use standard `for(;;)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `for (i in options)` iterates through the properties of the options object. [`for/in` was made to iterate over enumerable properties.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

> Array indexes are just enumerable properties with integer names and
>   are otherwise identical to general Object properties. **There is no
>   guarantee that for...in will return the indexes in any particular
>   order and it will return all enumerable properties, including those
>   with non–integer names and those that are inherited.**

So, while you may find some iterations of `forEach` or you can roll out your own, it is safer to loop over an array using a normal for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Try iterating through a general for loop.

```
for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    texts.push(options[i].innerText)
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d02urj1n/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jquery use $.map() like so...

```
var opts = $("select > option:not(:first-child)");
var texts = [];
$.map(opts, function(val, key){
    texts.push(val.innerText);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use basic **[JavaScript For Loop](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp)**, just like following :

```
for (var i=0 ; i < options.length ; i++){
    console.log(options[i]);
}

//That will give you the expected result
<option>text1</option>
<option>text2</option>
<option>text3</option>
```

**NOTE :** Please take a look at **[Why is using “for…in” with array iteration such a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea)**.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Looping through the properties in the object gives you the following items:

```
"0":      <option>text1</option>
"1":      <option>text2</option>
"2":      <option>text3</option>
"length": 3
"item":   function () {[native code]}
```

The reason that you get a `length` and `item` property also, is that the object is not an array, it's a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) object. It works as an array for methods that expect an array because it has a `length` property and numbered items, so it's what's called an array-like object. The `for( in )` loop doesn't expect an array.

Loop through the items as if it was an array, using the `length` property:

```
var texts = [];
for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++){
  texts.push(options[i].innerText);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, after some more inspection I did find some injected code objects! The standard for loop worked as expected. I didn't realize that for... in... would bring in inherited properties. Learn something new everyday.